# How to set HostName of Server on Firebrid Client using Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird, hostname

I have developed a client/server application using a firebird db and Delphi XE2. The problem is that the TSQLConnection component on the client automatically sets the HostName propery to localhost. I would like to know, how can I write code that will give the user the option to set the HostName when the client starts the first time.

I placed the TSQLConnection component on a datamodule on the client.

On the main form, I placed an option for the user to set the HostName propery with the following code assigning the value that the user entered into the TextBox:

```
Database.SQLServer.Params.Add('HostName='+edtHostName.Text);
```

But it seems that once the program starts the TSQLConnection component sets the hostname to localhost and I cannot set it to the users Hostname. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hostname is not a valid property for the dbexpress firebird connections,  instead you must use the the `DataBase` property to specify the host using one of these formats.

1) specifing the port , host and database

```
  server_host/port:/path/to/database.fdb
```

2) specifing the host and database

```
  server_host:/path/to/database.fdb
```

3) specifing only the database

```
/path/to/database.fdb
```

So using DbExpress this will look like

```
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Database']:='192.168.1.125/3050:C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\examples\empbuild\EMPLOYEE.FDB';
```

Comment: Do you have to use the IP address, or can you enter the hostname for example SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Database']:='HostName/3050:C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\examples\empbuild\EMPLOYEE.FDB';

Comment: If the host is in a LAN, you can use the hostname without problems, but I prefer use always the IP of the host.

Answer (score 0):

Check [embarcadero Wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection#Specifying_connection_parameters) is sometimes useful

> Specifying connection parameters
>
> The Params property is a string list that lists name-value pairs. Each
>   pair has the form Name=Value, where Name is the name of the parameter,
>   and Value is the value you want to assign. The particular parameters
>   you need depend on the database server you are using. However, one
>   particular parameter, Database, is required for all servers. Its value
>   depends on the server you are using. For example, with InterBase,
>   Database is the name of the .gdb file, with ORACLE it is the entry in
>   TNSNames.ora, while with DB2, it is the client-side node name. Other
>   typical parameters include the User_Name (the name to use when logging
>   in), Password (the password for User_Name), HostName (the machine name
>   or IP address of where the server is located), and TransIsolation (the
>   degree to which transactions you introduce are aware of changes made
>   by other transactions). When you specify a driver name, the Params
>   property is preloaded with all the parameters you need for that driver
>   type, initialized to default values. You can also add other connection
>   parameters to the Params string list, according to your application's
>   needs. For example, to provide Multiple Active Result Set (MARS)
>   support to a SQL connection using the MSSQL driver, you must add a key
>   called Mars_Connection and set its value to True. Because Params is a
>   string list, at design time, you can double-click the Params property
>   in the Object Inspector to edit the parameters using the String List
>   editor. At run time, use the Params.Values property to assign values
>   to individual parameters.